# How to create typescript variable with type FileList that is empty

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I recently took a coding test where I had to built a react app that uploaded a file. Typescript was used. I wanted to use the useState hook to store the file that was uploaded and I needed to establish the default value. Normally, you can simply set it to a string, number, empty object of the proper type, etc. However, how do I do this with a type FileList?

Something like :

```
let tempFile:FileList = ? 
let tempFile:FileList = <FileList>{} 
const [fileVar, setFileVar]=useState(tempFile);
```

Thanks

Comment: How would you have done this without TypeScript? It's hard to understand your requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface FileList {
  name: string;
}
let tempFile = [] as FileList[];
const [fileVar, setFileVar]=useState<FileList[]>(tempFile);
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't think that would work. Later, when you actually go to upload the file, it will conflict with that interface type.

Comment: i write the interface type just a example
more type need you add

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is using: FileList | null.

```
const [fileVar, setFileVar]=useState<FileList | null>(null);
```

And when to use, just check `fileVar` is `null` or not:

```
if(fileVar){
  ...your logic with fileVar
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well. Later, when I added the button to upload the file, I got an error that the operation could not be completed if it was possibly null ( you couldn't pull a file out of null).

Comment: You just to check `fileVar` before use as I updated